# In TypeScript, object returns union of two types and yet an error is generated

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, object returns union of two types and yet an error is generated .

Here is the main method:

`public getSelected(): ISimpleListItem | { [key: string]: ISimpleListItem } {
        if (this.multiSelect) // true of false
            return this.m_metadata; // metadata is when MANY ISimpleListItem  returned`

```
// single ISimpleItem returned    
for (let v in this.m_metadata) {
        if (this.m_metadata[v].selected == true)
            return this.m_metadata[v];
    }
}
```

```

notice that it can return both a single ISimpleListItem  as well as an object literal holding MANY ISimpleListItem(s)

The interface:

```
 export interface  ISimpleListItem {
        item: any,
        index: number,
        selected: boolean
    }
```

The method that uses simpleList.getSelected() in this case will receice just a single ISimpleList item

`private onSelecting(event) {
        var orderSelected:ISimpleListItem = this.simpleList.getSelected();
        this.selectedAdnetPackageModel = orderSelected.item;
    }`

you can see source here:

https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/blob/master/src/comps/app1/adnet/network/AdnetNetworkPackageEditor.ts

https://github.com/born2net/studioDashboard/blob/master/src/comps/app1/adnet/network/

and yet the error persists of:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right then:

```
let myObject: { [key: string]: ISimpleListItem } = {
    "key1": {
        index: 1,
        item: "something",
        selected: true
    }
};
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20%20ISimpleListItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20item%3A%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20index%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20selected%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20myObject%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ISimpleListItem%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22key1%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20index%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20item%3A%20%22something%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20selected%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B))

---

#### Edit

A union type is a type of its own and you can not treat it as if it is one of the types in the union without letting the compiler know which type you refer to.
There are a couple of ways to do that:

(1) [Type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

```
function getit(): string | { [key: string]: string } {
    return null;
}

let a = getit();
console.log(a.length); // error: Property length does not exist on type 'string | { [key: string]: string; }
console.log((a as string).length); // ok
```

(2) [Type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

```
if (typeof a === "string") {
    console.log(a); // ok
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20getit()%3A%20string%20%7C%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20getit()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(a.length)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Property%20length%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'string%20%7C%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log((a%20as%20string).length)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(typeof%20a%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(a)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: Toda! appreciate it!

Comment: I guess its not supported yet (ts 2.0) on unions: public getSelected(): ISimpleListItem | { [key: string]: ISimpleListItem } {...} basically a method that returns either one ISimpleItem or many...

Comment: It is supported, even before version 2.0

Comment: when I tried it, the calling method of getSelected() receives a TS error of: Error:(82, 56) TS2339: Property 'item' does not exist on type 'ISimpleListItem | { [key: string]: ISimpleListItem; }'.

Comment: this is how I call it this.simpleList.getSelected().item where getSelected is typed as the union type

Comment: if it returns either a `ISimpleListItem` or a map of those, then why would it have `.item`?  if it's a map you'll need to do `result[key].item`

Comment: ya that is what I would expect as well.. I updated the original question with snapshot and called method as per your recommended changes, as well as the error I get... tx!

Comment: I can't really understand what's going on there, you'll need to add the actual code to your question so I'll be able to see what are these `this.simpleList` and `this.simpleList.getSelected()` and `this.selectedAdnetPackageModel`

Comment: tx again, so I went and updated the question above. basically I have a method that can return either one ISimpleItem or many via object literal... and getting an error of: Error:(87, 13) TS2322: Type 'ISimpleListItem | { [key: string]: ISimpleListItem; }' is not assignable to type 'ISimpleListItem'.
 Type '{ [key: string]: ISimpleListItem; }' is not assignable to type 'ISimpleListItem'.
 Property 'item' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: ISimpleListItem; }'.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: TX, I understand, I was under the impression the compiler should be able to infer this or that, as long as one matches... but I guess not, I guess you still need to help it understand which type it is on the receiving end, tx!